# Calculate value of all numeric variables for empty rows based on previous and next row of same id

Tags: r, loops, time-series, interpolation, apply

I have a very large data.frame (thousands of variables) each row having an identifier and a year. A row might appear for several years or appear in the middle of the data. One year is missing (1997) and I want to interpolate the values of all numeric variables in a certain way:

1. Copy all rows from previous year (1996) who's identifier exist in
   the next year (1998).
2. For all numeric variables, calculate the mean of the previous year's variable with next year's - of the specific two corresponding rows (with the same identifier).
3. As this is a very large data set, I am eager to avoid using loops.

Example data:

```
test_df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,1,3), year = c(96,96,96,98,98), 
                      state = c("MA","MD","NY","MA", "NY"),
                      num1 = c(10,11,22,9,27), num2 = c(11566,32340,97555,14200,100025))
> test_df
  id year state num1   num2
1  1   96    MA   10  11566
2  2   96    MD   11  32340
3  3   96    NY   22  97555
4  1   98    MA    9  14200
5  3   98    NY   27 100025
```

And the final data should be:

```
  id year state num1   num2
1  1   96    MA   10  11566
2  2   96    MD   11  32340
3  3   96    NY   22  97555
4  1   97    MA  9.5  12883
5  3   97    NY 24.5  98790
6  1   98    MA    9  14200
7  3   98    NY   27 100025
```

What I did so far was sub-setting the rows from the previous year that have the same id's as next year, and selecting numeric variables. After the computation, I would just `rbind` them to the main data.

```
common_ids <- test_df[test_df$year==1996,]
common_ids <- common_ids[test_df[test_df$year==1996,]$id %in% test_df[test_df$year==1998,]$id,]
numeric_vars <- sapply(common_ids,is.numeric)

common_ids[,numeric_vars] <- lapply(common_ids[,numeric_vars], function(x)???)
```

Final question - will the solution work also if two years are missing in a row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` and `zoo` you could start with something like this

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

test_df <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,1,3), year = c(96,96,96,98,98), 
                  state = c("MA","MD","NY","MA", "NY"),
                  num1 = c(10,11,22,9,27), num2 = c(11566,32340,97555,14200,100025))

test_df <- test_df[order(id, year)]

missing.ids <- test_df[, c(NA, id[-.N]), by = id][!is.na(V1),V1]

temp_df <- data.table(id = missing.ids, year = rep(97, length(missing.ids)), state = NA, num1 = NA, num2 = NA)

new.test_df <- rbind(test_df, temp_df)[order(id, year)]

new.test_df[, state := na.locf(state, na.rm = FALSE), by = id]
new.test_df[, `:=` (num1 = na.approx(num1, na.rm = FALSE), num2 = na.approx(num2, na.rm = FALSE)), by = id]
```

**EDIT**
Without naming specific variables

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

test_df <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,1,3), year = c(96,96,96,98,98), 
                  state = c("MA","MD","NY","MA", "NY"),
                  num1 = c(10,11,22,9,27), num2 = c(11566,32340,97555,14200,100025))

test_df <- test_df[order(id, year)]

mynum.cols <- names(test_df)[!(names(test_df) %in% c("id", "year", "state"))]
missing.ids <- test_df[, c(NA, id[-.N]), by = id][!is.na(V1),V1]

temp_df <- data.table(id = missing.ids, year = rep(97, length(missing.ids)), state = NA, 
                  data.table(matrix(NA, nrow = length(missing.ids), ncol = length(mynum.cols), 
                                    dimnames = list(rep(NA, length(missing.ids)), mynum.cols))))

new.test_df <- rbind(test_df, temp_df)[order(id, year)]

new.test_df[, state := na.locf(state, na.rm = FALSE), by = id]

new.test_df[, (mynum.cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE)), by = id, .SDcols = mynum.cols]

new.test_df <- new.test_df[order(year, id)]
new.test_df
```

Comment: Can you do this without naming specific variables (there are thousands)?

Comment: you can create a vector of column names and loop through it using `data.table`'s `set`. don't have time today but maybe someone can update my answer with that